# Are there any resources for creating terms and conditions for websites?

Tags: privacy, eula, data-storage

I am currently on the process of making a forum based website that will contain users emails, passwords and possibly names. When The users signs up they will need to accept the terms and conditions but at the moment they are empty. Are there any resources on creating terms and conditions of any pre-built one's that are available?

If not may someone please provide me with the base lines.

Sorry if this is posted on the wrong section but I felt this was quite serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TOS for a website is serious business; you need to precisely outline how your user's data is protected, what users can and can't do in the forum, your responsibilities to the users, and on and on.

Your TOS is a legal document. Your users sign a contract when they click and accept. See Contracts of Adhesion https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/adhesion_contract_contract_of_adhesion

If you copy and paste a pre-made TOS, and don't understand exactly what is in it, and you and your users are bound by that TOS, what kind of legal risks do you open yourself up to?

The copy and paste of someone else's TOS can be a copyright violation: [Is it legal to copy a sites terms of use?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/is-it-legal-to-copy-a-sites-terms-of-use/7903#7903)

A simple Google search yields https://formswift.com/terms-of-service among others. Or try one of the many services like LegalZoom. But if you're serious about the site and you and your users' legal protections, you'll have a TOS professionally drafted.

Comment: Cut-and-paste also runs the risk of being copyright infringement.

Comment: True; I should have linked an earlier question: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/is-it-legal-to-copy-a-sites-terms-of-use/7903#7903

Comment: So I could have absolutely no security on the data I had stored and just explain that in the TOS without any repercussions?

Comment: That's really a question asking for legal advice, which is off-topic here and I don't want to hazard an answer. You should talk to a lawyer about your liabilities of no security even with a TOS that states that.

Comment: The minimum required level of security will depend on your local laws, and on the kind of data that your site holds. If it is people's individual personal data, the level may well be higher than zero, depending on your jurisdiction. I would strongly advise consulting an expert to whom you can describe your specific situation.